# Powershell - "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline"

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

How can I avoid this error in the below circumstance?

```
$codegenDir = "Z:\Desktop\Song-Renamer"
$PowerShellRepresentation = dir -path $MyMusicFolder -recurse -include *.mp3,*.m4a,*.wma,*.flac,*.ape | select -ExpandProperty FullName | $codegenDir\codegen.exe -s 10 20 | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
```

What puzzles me is if simply omit $codegenDir (see below), the code operates correctly.  I *think* I understand the concept of placing the expression first (ahead of other items in the pipeline.  But I'm not sure how to rearrange/split this code so the expression in question *the Codegen.exe external commandline* is the first item in the pipeline (and still be able to pass data to it via pipeline).

```
$PowerShellRepresentation = dir -path $MyMusicFolder -recurse -include *.mp3,*.m4a,*.wma,*.flac,*.ape | select -ExpandProperty FullName | .\codegen.exe -s 10 20 | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Ideally, it would be nice to do this using the least amount of code as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give the following a shot (only difference is the &):

```
$PowerShellRepresentation = dir -path $MyMusicFolder -recurse -include *.mp3,*.m4a,*.wma,*.flac,*.ape | select -ExpandProperty FullName | & $codegenDir\codegen.exe -s 10 20 | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Here's [a link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx#Invoke-Item_II) to a technet article about executing commands in powershell in different ways.