# How to Prevent Powershell from "Caching" Piped Data

Tags: powershell, pipe, powershell-2.0

I have the following command that executes in a command window:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnadmin.exe" dump --quiet "C:\svnrepo" | "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -si "C:\svnbak.7z"
```

This will dump the contents of my SVN repository into an accepting 7-zip instance which writes the contents compressed to a disk. When the command is running, I can observe the 7z file increase as it runs until completion.

When trying to put in into a Powershell v2 script, I [altered it](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx) to:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnadmin.exe" dump --quiet "C:\svnrepo" | "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -si "C:\svnbak.7z"
```

It complained that "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline". Based off another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034328/powershell-expressions-are-only-allowed-as-the-first-element-of-a-pipeline), I altered the command to this:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnadmin.exe" dump --quiet "C:\svnrepo" | & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -si "C:\svnbak.7z"
```

The Powershell script appears to run but instead of seeing the file slowly being written to, only my memory increase. I'm assuming instead of writing the contents to the 7-zip process, Powershell is "caching" the contents until the dump is completed. When the dump finishes, the contents will be pushed to 7-zip. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening (to get the same results as the initial command)?

Comment: The & operator is a nightmare to deal with when you have commands and parameters with spaces. You could try putting the 7zip expression inside parenthesis or into a scriptblock and try executing that.

Comment: To get rid of the & operator, try `New-Alias 7z "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"`, then you can use `7z` instead of `& "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"`

Comment: This is a really interesting issue. I tried piping a 35MB text file to 7z and PowerShell uses 500MB of RAM to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This more of a suggestion than a solution, but it might help your situation. I experimented with this a lot and I can't get the data to flush to 7z until it's all loaded into memory (and then some). My hunch is that "normal" shells take the stdout of the first command and stream it to stdin of the second command when you use the pipe. With PowerShell everything is an object. So it's trying to pass objects across and doesn't know what kind of object to pass until it's all loaded. If your first command produced an array of strings and the second could consume an array from the pipeline, it would probably work as expected.

Here's the partial solution:

```
New-Alias svnadmin "C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnadmin.exe"
New-Alias 7z "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
svnadmin dump --quiet "C:\svnrepo" > snvdump.txt 
Get-Content svndump.txt | 7z a -si "C:\svnbak.7z"
```

This uses about 1/5 as much memory as the form solution, but still more than it should. It also doesn't flush the data to 7z until it's all loaded, so may not work depending on the size of your dump.

---

**Update:** Since it works in CMD and not PowerShell (and svnadmin and 7z are console apps and not cmdlets), why not just call CMD?

```
 CMD /C """C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnadmin.exe"" dump --quiet ""C:\svnrepo"" | ""C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"" a -si ""C:\SourceCode\svnbak.7z"""
```

Note, I don't have svn on my machine, so I did it with a large text file:

```
CMD /C "type files.txt | ""C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"" a -si ""C:\SourceCode\svnbak.7z"""
```

`CMD` should be in your path, so it should just work. It was much faster on my machine and used next to no memory.

Comment: Great information. Trying to use the CMD approach but it still does not work for me as PowerShell performs some unwanted parsing. `CMD /C "svnadmin dump ...` works (when the command is in my path) but `CMD /C """C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnadmin.exe"" dump ...` fails to work (error "... not recognized as an internal or external command ...").

Comment: As a side note I've stumbled upon PowerShell's stop-parsing symbol `--%` which might have helped, but it doesn't work in v2.0.